# Call Initialize after simple ctor and after MVC parameters are bound

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I am using autofac and MVC together to allow me to auto resolve view models.  This works well although I have an issue where I need to call an Initializable method for every view model after it is resolved.

I solved this issue by simply hooking into the OnActivated method within autofac.

The only issue here is that the Initialize method is called before the MVC has bound its parameters to the properties within the view model, therefore resulting in partial initialization.

I can solve this by adding the call (removing from autofac) to Initialize in my OnModelUpdated override of my custom ModelBinder, although now if I create a view model outside the MVC binding it won't call initialize.

The only solution I can see is to have it in both places, Autofac (OnActivated) and in my modelbinder (OnModelUpdated), this will be a tremendous performance hit surely, any ideas?