# Autofac "action injection" with ASP.NET MVC model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm using Autofac with ASP.NET MVC and am wondering if my view model setup in the web project is a good approach or not.  In the past I only used constructer injection at the Controller level but thought it would be interesting to see if everything could be injected via Autofac.

Let's say I have a view model that looks this:

```
public class CollegeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private CollegeModel _model { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CollegeViewModel(ICsnCache cache, CollegeModel model)
    {
        this._cache = cache;
        this._model = model;
    }

    public void Populate() { /* TODO: */ }
    public void Update() { /* TODO: */ }
}
```

- Cache is to access code sets (i.e. for drop down lists)
- The model has methods that are called from the view model (e.g. Save())

This is where things get a bit strange.  I found myself having to create a custom action invoker which derives from `System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker`.  Autofac has one of these already `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.ExtensibleActionInvoker`.  The problem I found with the one built into Autofac is that it stopped the default model binding. i.e. it succeeded in injecting my dependencies but then the rest of the view model properties were empty even though the POST had valid form data.

This is a combination of Autofac and ASP.NET MVC code (taken out some validation and comments for readability):

```
public class CustomExtensibleActionInvoker : System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override object GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
    {
        object value = null;
        try
        {
            value = base.GetParameterValue(controllerContext, parameterDescriptor);
        }
        catch (MissingMethodException) { }

        if (value == null)
        {
            // We got nothing from the default model binding, so try to resolve it.
            var context = Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope;
            value = context.ResolveOptional(parameterDescriptor.ParameterType);

            // This is the part I added, which is from the ASP.NET MVC source code
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                FallbackToEmptyPrefix = (parameterDescriptor.BindingInfo.Prefix == null), // only fall back if prefix not specified
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => value, parameterDescriptor.ParameterType),
                ModelName = parameterDescriptor.BindingInfo.Prefix ?? parameterDescriptor.ParameterName,
                ModelState = controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState,
                PropertyFilter = GetPropertyFilter(parameterDescriptor),
                ValueProvider = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider,
            };

            value = System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private Predicate<string> GetPropertyFilter(ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
    {
        ParameterBindingInfo bindingInfo = parameterDescriptor.BindingInfo;
        return propertyName => IsPropertyAllowed(propertyName, bindingInfo.Include, bindingInfo.Exclude);
    }

    private bool IsPropertyAllowed(string propertyName, ICollection<string> includeProperties, ICollection<string> excludeProperties)
    {
        bool includeProperty = (includeProperties == null) || (includeProperties.Count == 0) || includeProperties.Contains(propertyName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        bool excludeProperty = (excludeProperties != null) && excludeProperties.Contains(propertyName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return includeProperty && !excludeProperty;
    }
}
```

I realise I'm always using the default model binder, but that could be enhanced if I ever needed other model binders.

Could it be a bug in Autofac (the fact model binding doesn't happen but the DI works) or am I misusing the framework?

Note that this does work, but since it's early days I'm worried I might be adding complexity and maybe should just handle some dependency injection myself.

Edit (tweaked Ruskin's code to suit my app):

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If the model type is registered in our Autofac configuration,
    /// use that, otherwise let MVC create the model as per usual
    /// </summary>        
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var item = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(modelType);

        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // removed other code for readability    
    System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyCustomModelBinder();
}
```

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` canot bind to a model if the model not have a parameterless constructor (I'm surprised your not getting an exception for that). But a view model should not contain any of that code anyway - just properties for use by the view.

Comment: I'm using Autofac, so there's no need for a default constructor (happy to include the Autofac configuration if it helps clarify things).  The view model has access to the model - so for example the view model Update() will simply be calling _model.Update().  I've done it the other way in the past too, where you put some of that logic in the Controller rather than view model, but either way seems fine to me.

Comment: Do you specify `.PropertiesAutowired()` when you register controllers with the container builder?

Comment: @zaitsman - not exactly sure what that extension does so I've included the Autofac configuration I currently have.  I played around with that extension in the configuration but couldn't get the same behaviour I currently have (i.e. DI + model binding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question (I think that's your question):

> The problem I found with the one built into Autofac is that it stopped the default model binding. i.e. it succeeded in injecting my dependencies but then the rest of the view model properties were empty even though the POST had valid form data.

I don't think it's a bug in Autofac, I believe the model resolution happens well before the MVC has bound it's properties into the view model, so when are you expecting the properties to be present in the view model?

I had the exact same issue: have a a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699724/call-initialize-after-simple-ctor-and-after-mvc-parameters-are-bound)

Edit:

This is your autofac registration where *builder* is your ContainerBuilder...

```
var types = LoadMyViewModels(); // Do some reflection to get all your viewmodels
foreach (var type in types)
{
    Type modelBinderType = typeof(MyCustomModelBinder<>);
    Type[] typeArgs = { modelType };

    Type genType = modelBinderType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
    object viewmodel = Activator.CreateInstance(genType);
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(modelType, (IModelBinder)viewmodel);

    var registeredType = builder.RegisterType(modelType).AsSelf();
}
```

CustomModelBinder

```
[ModelBinderType]
public class MyCustomModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder where T : class
{
    [NotNull]
    protected override object CreateModel([NotNull] ControllerContext controllerContext, [NotNull] ModelBindingContext bindingContext, [NotNull] Type modelType)
    {
        var item = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();

        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("model type {0} is not registered", modelType.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ruskin.  I just need the properties to be bound as per usual, i.e. by the time I hit the first line in the action method.  The main problem is when you ask Autofac to inject an action method dependency, you're taking that responsibility away from MVC and therefore model binding doesn't occur. I suppose I had a couple of questions in one (sorry for any confusion):
- Does Autofac have a way of injecting without stopping model binding
- Is my solution acceptable (i.e. the custom action invoker that I register with Autofac)

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you a possible solution although I still have the issue where, at time of injection, the properties aren't bound, because as I mentioned the ctor injection occurs well before the MVC model binding.  Rest assured the model binding does happen

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, will test when I get home tonight.  But I'm not sure why it's an issue that the properties wouldn't be bound at that stage - in fact I don't think it's possible?  I'd suggest you need to tinker with your design if you're having that problem.  I think the custom action invoker in my question is the closest you'll get to DI + model binding.

Comment: Thanks @Ruskin, works great.  I originally tried using a custom model binder but didn't think to only override the CreateModel and use Autofac conditionally.  I tweaked your code a bit and have included in my question in case anyone wants to see what I ended up with.